# Checking and uncheck check box's with class. Fails after first uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a group of checkbox's and one of them is marked as all. If this is clicked i would like to check all the other checkbox's within this class, and if it is then clicked again i want to remove the check form all the checkbox's within that class.

At the moment when i check all, all my checkbox's are checked, then when i click all again, all the checkbox's become unchecked. **If i try click all again only the all check box is clicked.**

When the all check box is checked i run:

```
$('.chIndustry').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

When the all checkbox becomes unchecked:

```
$('.chIndustry').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: How do you determine which is the 'all' button? Representative HTML often helps, with JavaScript questions.

Comment: show some html code it is useful for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".checkall").change(function() {
        console.log($(this).is(':checked'))
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('input[name="test"]').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('input[name="test"]').prop('checked',false );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test" />
<input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test" />
<input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test" />
<input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test" />
<input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test" /></br/>
Check all    <input type="checkbox"  class="checkall" />
```

The above works as per your requirement..

Comment: I have amy group's of check box's so cant use input[name=test] unless the name is class?

Comment: Even though this code works, it is worth mentioning that `checked` is Boolean attribute, as said in [W3C forms specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4). So in proper way it should be `prop('checked', true);` and `prop('checked', false);`

Comment: @Pomster you can modify selector from `$('input[name="test"]')` to `$('.chIndustry')` as mentioned in Sam1604's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.prop` to uncheck the check the check box

```
$('.chIndustry').prop('checked', false);
```